# What is the relationship between the vector fields defined by $\dot{x}=Ax$ and $\dot{x}=kAx$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems

**What is the relationship between the vector fields defined by
$\dot{x}=Ax$ and $\dot{x}=kAx$
where k is a non-zero constant? (Describe this relationship both for
$k$ positive and $k$ negative.)**

I know that the solution of $\dot{x}=Ax$ is $x(t)=e^{At}x_0$ and that of $\dot{x}=kAx$ is $x(t)=e^{kAt}x_0$, and with this I get to $e^{At}=e^{kAt}$ but I do not know what else to conclude, could anyone help me with this please? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume they mean "for the same initial condition $x(0) = x_0.$" You're right about the solutions.

So let $x_1(t) = e^{At}x_0$ and $x_2(t) =  e^{kAt}x_0 = e^{A(kt)}x_0.$ Then we have $x_2(t) = x_1(kt). $

We can even see it at the level of the original equation using the chain rule: $$ \frac{d}{dt}x_2(t) = \frac{d}{dt}x_1(kt) = k x_1'(kt) = kAx_1(kt) = kAx_2(t).$$

A nice way to look at it is that changing $k$ is equivalent to just changing the units of time (with negative $k$ amounting to a time reversal).

Comment: [+1] ... thus the trajectories are the same ; the only difference is that they are "travelled" at a different speed.